# Add canvas in TableLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I use Xamarin Android.
How I can add Canvas in TableLayout?

Can I convert Andoid.Graphics to Android.Widget?

```
        var layout = new TableLayout(this);

        PointF[] _points = new[]
                                        {
                                            new PointF(100, 100),
                                            new PointF(800, 800)
                                       };

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        var path = new Path();
        path.MoveTo(_points[0].X, _points[0].Y);
        for (var i = 1; i < _points.Length; i++)
        {
            path.LineTo(_points[i].X, _points[i].Y);
        }
        var paint = new Paint
        {
            Color = Color.White
        };
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.StrokeWidth = 3;
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        layout.AddView(canvas); //not working
```

Comment: extend TableLayout and override its draw() or dispatchDraw() metods

Comment: please, can you write here this method Draw() for TableLayout. It's very difficult for me.